# Firebase remove ValueEventListener doesn't remove listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have 2 listeners to Firebase Real-time database: connection listener and data listener. I declared those variables globally with keyword `val` and in `init{}` block I've initialized them. Having said that they **should not** be changed. So, also in my `init` block I attach Connection listener to `DatabaseReference`. If device is connected to Firebase it calls a method to attach data listener.

**So, what's the problem?**
As theoretically Listeners stays the same, so I can attach them and remove with any problem. But the problem is, once listener is attached to a reference I can no longer remove them - or in other words, after removing a listener from reference data is still fetched.

**Code:**

Firebase class where listeners are attached:

```
private val REFERENCE = "reference"

private var mDatabase: FirebaseDatabase? = null
private val mDataReference: DatabaseReference
private val mValueChangedListener: ValueEventListener

private var mModelChanged: onModelChanged? = null

init {
    if (mDatabase == null) {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    }
    mDataReference = mDatabase!!.getReference(REFERENCE)

    /**
     * Listener listening for data changes
     */

    mValueChangedListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            mModelChanged?.onDataSetChanged(p0)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            mModelChanged?.onConnectionChanged(false)
            Log.e("Database error", p0.code.toString())
        }
    }
}

fun attachListener(){
    mDataReference.addValueEventListener(mValueChangedListener)
    Log.d("Attach listener", "attached")
}

fun detachListener(){
    mDataReference.removeEventListener(mValueChangedListener)
    Log.d("Detach listener", "detached")

}
```

Repository which calls attachListener() or detachListener() from class above, also it sets up an interface `onModelChanged`.

```
fun attachAdapter(){
    mModel.attachListener()
}

fun detachAdapter(){
    mModel.detachListener()
}
```

And Activity, which calls repo in `onResume()` and `onPause()`

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mRepository.attachAdapter()
    Log.i("onResume", "called")
}


override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mRepository.detachAdapter()
    Log.i("onPause", "called")
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to add and remove a listener in response to a connection state change?  When your app loses a connection, the listeners won't fire anyway.  When your app regains a connection, it will fire the listeners if something changed what it was offline.  The listeners will still fire if the app changes data locally while offline, which is helpful for your app to remain usable while offline.

Comment: yay you're right again. I've just removed unnecessary code and have only data listener. Still if I call `detachListener()` to remove this data listener, data is still being fetched.

Comment: Would you like to show exactly how you're calling those methods?  As it stands right now, we can't see if you are doing that correctly.

Comment: @DougStevenson just updated the code. I attach/detach listeners at `onPause()` and `onResume()`

Comment: It should be OK.  There must be something else going on.  Put breakpoints in your code that adds and removes listeners to see if the code is actually being called the way you expect.